# Creating multiple draggable objects in java

Tags: java, object, draggable

In this program, when I press a key and click on the screen, it's supposed to draw a square with that letter in it that's supposed to be draggable. The program can draw the square just fine, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to make each icon draggable. Here's the code I'm working with. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 class CLetter {
public CLetter (int x0, int y0, char name) {
    Xs=new double[4];
    Ys=new double[4];
    NAME=name;
    int tempX = x0 +50;
    int tempY = y0 -50;
    Xs[0]=x0;   Ys[0]=y0;
    Xs[1]=tempX; Ys[1]=y0;
    Xs[2]=x0;   Ys[2]=tempY;
    Xs[3]=tempX; Ys[3]=tempY;
    }
}
private boolean isLeft(int x, int y, int id) {
    return (y-Ys[id])*(Xs[(id+1)%4]-Xs[id])<(x-Xs[id])*(Ys[(id+1)%4]-Ys[id]);
    }
public boolean isInside(int x, int y) {
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        if (!isLeft(x, y, i)) return false;
    }
return true;
    }
public void translate(int dx, int dy) {
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        Xs[i] += dx;
        Ys[i] += dy;
    }
}
private int X;
private int Y;
private char NAME;
private double[] Xs;
private double[] Ys;
}
```

Comment: Please provide only that part of code where u are facing problems

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem is. I think it's in either the mouseDragged or mousePressed functions.

Comment: just debug the cod and get idea...

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to Java. I edited the original post to only include the problem functions. When I click on one of the CLetter objects, the function isInside is supposed to return True, but it never does.

Comment: it looks me a plain java program, where is your swing class or frame?